# Simple question concerning definition of the equivalence relation and the group operation in quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-group

I have simple, yet critical questions for my understanding on the quotient group $G/H$.
Remember that $H$ is a sub group of $G$. So we say that, for any given element $x,y \in G$, $x$ and $y$ are equivalent (written $x\sim y$) iff $x*y^{-1} \in H$. And we write $G/H$ the set of all equivalent classes.

*My questions are:*

1. How can we know how the equivalent relation “$\sim$” is defined?
   For example, in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ two numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$ are equivalent iff they have the same rest after the euclidian division by $p$.
   But in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ two numbers $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ are said to be equivalent iff $x-y=0$.
2. How can I know how or what is the operation noted “$*$” of the group $G$? I need to know it in order to know $g^{-1}$ (that must verify $g*g^{-1}=e$, $e$ the neutral element of the operation “$*$”)?

Is there some general convention that I should know?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Convention, $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group is equipped with addition. It makes sense because if it was multiplication, $0$ (which is in $\mathbb{Z}$) wouldn't have an inverse. Same goes for $\mathbb{R}$.

From this you can understand why the equivalence relation of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is $x - y \in p\mathbb{Z}$ (which is the same as $x$ and $y$ having the same rest after euclidian division by $p$), and why for $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, it is $x - y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $(\mathbb{Z},*)$ where $*$ is multiplication is not a group.

Answer (score 1):

To verify that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, you must check the following:

- Reflexivity: For all $x \in G$, we have $x \sim x$
- Symmetry: For all $x, y \in G$, if $x \sim y$, then $y \sim x$
- Transitivity: For all $x, y, z \in G$, if $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$, then $x \sim z$

For example, reflexivity is seen by noting that for all $x \in G$, we have $x * x^{-1} = e \in H$ since $H$ is a subgroup. Can you check the other two axioms similarly?

With regard to your question about the operation $*$, whenever people talk about a group $G$, the operation $*$ is inherently part of the data of $G$ (otherwise, $G$ would just be a set). I guess the extremely precise way to say this would be to say that $(G, *)$ is a group.

Comment: Thk you for your time. I know the definition of the equivalent relation.  My problem is that in most questions the equivalent relation is not precise (i.e. the exemples I have given where the equivalent relation is not the same). Moreover is there something I must assume on the operation $"*"$ when I work on $\mathbb{R}$ (or a sub group of $ \mathbb{R}$ )?

Comment: The correct equivalence relation for $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to $\mathbb{Z}$ is supposed to be that for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $(x - y) \in \mathbb{Z}$ rather than $x - y = 0$. For $\mathbb{Z}$ with respect to $p\mathbb{Z}$, saying that $x$ and $y$ leave the same remainder modulo $p$ precisely means that $(x - y) \in p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @X0-user-0X The equivalence relation depends on context, in other words, ~ may denote different equivalence relations in different scenarios.

Comment: The operation $*$ is supposed to be the group operation. For instance, when people say $G = \mathbb{R}$ as a group, they implicitly mean that the operation is $+$. For $G = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, they implicitly mean that the operation is addition modulo $p$. For $G = \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$ as a group, they implicitly mean the operation is $\times$, and so on...

Comment: @Divide1918 thk I know this but in lot of question the equivalent relation $"\sim"$ is not defined and It is assume that I should know it.

Comment: @X0-user-0X Then it's just the canonical relation, which depends on context

Answer (score 0):

I think that this may help. Below a list of the main group with the operation that is associated to them.

- $(\mathbb{Z} ; +) , (\mathbb{R} ; +) , (\mathbb{C} ; +) , (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} ; +)$ with $+$ the casual addition.
- $(\mathbb{K}^*; \times)$ with $\mathbb{K}$ a mathematic field, $\mathbb{K}^*$ the set of all element of $\mathbb{K}$ that have an inverse with respect to the operation $ \times $ that is usually the comom multilpication. For exemple with $\mathbb{K}= \mathbb{C} \Rightarrow \mathbb{C}^* = $ the set of all complex number that are not zero.
- $ (GL_n(\mathbb{K}); \times )$ with $GL_n(\mathbb{K})$ the set of all $n×n$ invertible matrices over a field $\mathbb{K}$. This is a group with the operation of matrix multiplication "$ \times $" .
- $(S_n; \circ ) $  with $S_n$ the symetric set whose elements are all the possible bijections from the a finite set of size $n$ to itself and $\circ$ the composition of function.

*Rem:* More over generally as far as I know the "quotient group" $G/H$ (if it is a group and that must be checked), inherit of the operation of the group $G$.

*Edit:* A last precision in the case that we writte $G^*$ it implies that $G$ is a ring, and that $G^*$ is the set of all the elements invertible according to the segond law "$*$" of the ring $G$. More over $(G^*; \times)$ is a group of neutral element $1_G$.